# ViewDidLoad and UINavigationController in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, model-view-controller

I have an app which is based on a `UINavigationController`.  There is a menu screen with buttons that segue (push onto navigation controller stack) to one of 9 other "sub-screens".  None of these sub-screens segue to any other screen. When a user is done inputing data on a "sub-screen" they can press a done button which will pop back to the original menu screen.  (If you're having difficulty picturing this, imagine a tree like storyboard where there is one root ViewController and then 9 leaf viewControllers).

Ok, so with that setup I have a few questions about how `viewDidLoad` works.

~ First, is `viewDidLoad` supposed to be called every time we transition to a sub-screen. For example, suppose I go from the menu screen to sub-screen "B", back to the menu screen and then back to sub-screen "B". Should B's `viewDidLoad` method be called twice? If not, why might mine be getting called twice?

~ Second, assuming that it will get called each time, what do I do if I have a lot of long operations that need to be performed exactly one time for each sub-screen? Where should I put them (if I put them in `viewDidLoad` it would happen multiple times if the user kept going back and forth between this page and the menu)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, in general B's viewDidLoad method should be called each time that it is pushed onto the UINavigationController's stack. This is because each time that B is popped off of the stack it is typically released, and each time that you go to B a new instance of B is created.
2. There could be numerous ways to handle this type of situation. It is hard to tell what is right for you without seeing exactly what you are trying to do. One way would be to create a [singleton object](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html) that handles the processing. The reason this might be better than handling it within your UIViewController is that a singleton can live throughout the lifetime of the application, whereas UIViewControllers typically have a relatively short lifespan. Singleton objects can be created just once and they can manage whatever operations and data that you need to persist through the lifetime of your application.

Comment: viewDidLoad will be called only once for each time when the view has been "init"ed not everytime it is added onto the stack

Comment: I explained in my response that "each time that B is popped off of the stack it is typically released, and each time that you go to B a new instance of B is created" aka init/viewDidLoad will be called each time you visit B.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's typically released. viewDidUnload is only called on a view controller when the view property is released / set to nil and this typically only happens if the app receives a memory warning.

Comment: If you make sure to keep a reference to the viewController that you are, it is not released, thus you can reuse it. If the view takes long time to load, releasing it every time would not be recommended.

Comment: First of all every one is making many assumptions here. Has anyone even asked if he is initializing repeatedly? If that is the case then it will be called every time. Second, @Michael Frederick is right, when a navigation controller pops the view controller, it is indeed released, hence the "probable" need to create a new instance and assign it to that pointer. Until he answers the question as of how he is going by initializing that view controller everything is pure assumption. Before trying to be harsh on people and deducting points, documentation should be done.

Comment: The question asks whether viewDidLoad should be called every time the viewcontroller is pushed to a navigationcontroller, and if not, what might be the reason that it is. Truth is that it should be called whenever the view is loaded - no matter when this happens. That the viewcontroller is being released every time it is popped is one possible (and probable) reason for the behaviour described. No assumptions was made. Answer above states that this is the normal and correct way, but there are many other normal ways to do it and make it behave differently, which is why I countered the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

`viewWillAppear` gets called every time the view appears. `viewDidLoad` ONLY gets called when the view is constructed - so for example after a view controller `initFromNibNamed` call when the view is accessed. `viewWillAppear` is called anytime your view controller was not in view but comes into view - so when your view controller is pushed, `viewWillAppear` is called. So you might think your `viewDidLoad` is being called twice, but in reality it's probably not. So you should put the methods in `viewDidLoad`. What are you doing that takes a long time?

Answer (score 0):

1.
 viewDidLoad is called when the view is loaded, and viewWillAppear is called when the view becomes visible.

If your viewDidLoad is called several times that means that you are loading the view every time you are showing it and releasing it every time you are popping it. If you post some code I could help you identify the problem better.

What you could do is something like this:

In your "root" viewController class, declare each "leaf" ViewController as a member, lets say they are called leafController1, leafController2 etc and create retain-properties for them.

```
@interface YourRootViewController : UIViewController {
    LeafController1Class *leafController1;
    LeafController2Class *leafController2;
    // ...
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) LeafController1Class *leafController1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) LeafController2Class *leafController2;

// ...

@end
```

In the ViewDidLoad of your top ViewController, init all the leaf-controllers using "initWithNibName" etc (or whatever you are doing to create them). Retain their instances like so:

```
self.leafController1 = [[[LeafController1Class alloc] initWithNibName:@"LeafController1NibName" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

When the user presses a button, push the correct leaf to the navigationcontroller:

```
[myNavigationController pushViewController:leafController1 animated:YES];
```

When you pop the leaf controllers now, they will be kept in memory since you retained them.
This way your viewDidLoad will only be called once for each leaf, just as long as you always push the same instace of the viewcontroller to your navigationcontroller.

2.
Heavy code related to the view should be executed when the view has been loaded, i.e. triggered by viewDidLoad. But also it might be a good idea to keep other classes that hold info about your application which are not viewcontrollers and separate from the UI. Heavy computations is better made in the background, or when the app is loading for the first time.